# Bundle WCF service along with Universal Windows App

Tags: wcf, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10-universal

I realize that we cannot directly access SQL Server database from a UWP app, and have to use a WCF service as a mediator for this. (Which is totally stupid, since even competitors like MySQL provides API for Microsoft's runtime, while Microsoft's own RDBMS does not!)

I don't have any experience with WCF, but after going through some tutorials, I believe I can make a WCF service to communicate with my SQL Server (although I do not like making my simple application use a 3-tier architecture, which shouldn't be imposed on me). Anyways, I do not want to host this WCF service on my website, since I'm making this only for this UWP app. Is there a way I can bundle/pack this WCF service along with UWP app itself, such that service runs on client machine only when thhe start my app, and stops later when app is closed/suspended/minized.

The UWP app I'm developing, also have a WPF version and a web version (in ASP.NET), all of which were connected to MySQL database till now, and it worked flawless. Recently I decided to shift to SQL Server since I'm using Microsoft technologies for all my softwares and *thought* SQL Server will have better integration and support. But now I find it rather opposite, and thinking to switch back to MySQL database.

Comment: If you already have a website, why not just use the WebAPI to expose safely and securely the database, regardless of underlying tech you've picked?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Because I don't want this UWP to communicate with my website server and increase load on that, just for a simple task like connecting to a database that's residing on a totally different server.

Plus, I may decide to discontinue website. But I'd still want the UWP to function properly.

Comment: I'd Switch back to MySQL then, or switch to using Azure Sql.

Answer (score 2):

You can not bundle a WCF service (or REST api) with your Universal Windows app. UWP apps run in a sandbox environment on a different .NET runtime than your WCF service. You could run the WCF service in IIS, or even better create a self-hosted ASP.NET WebAPI project (so no need for IIS) to access your database. But this service will have to be **installed separately** from the app.

Note that because UWP apps run in a sandbox, some in-app databases like SQLite are inside this sandbox and can not be accessed by your other apps (WPF, website) by default (there are some hacks to bypass this).

So I think your best bet is to stick with MySQL and use the [MySQL connector](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_using_connector_net).

Comment: No these version are not on same machine. It's a casual app, so the user has a choice of using any version they want, hence I need a common database to reside on my server, that can be accessed from any platform the user choses.

It's a shame I have to chose MySQL instead Microsoft's own RDBMS, even for making apps inside Microsoft's ecosystem.

Comment: In that case I'd create a simple REST api (ASP.NET WebApi, php, ...) to query your database from the app and place it on some web server. That way you have full control over the code querying the database even when users don't upgrade their app.

Comment: That's what WiredPrairie suggested in comments too. And I stated my reason for not choosing this path. Guess I'll switch to MySQL for now.