# Can I host a WCF endpoint in a Universal Windows Application (UWP)?

Tags: web-services, wcf, win-universal-app

it's possible to host an endpoint of windows communication foundation (WCF) in a Universal Windows Application (UWP) or there is other ways to expose some endpoints in this UWP kind of apps

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460625/bundle-wcf-service-along-with-universal-windows-app

Comment: I made a research and I can't find a way to consume or create a service in a Windows Universal Application to communicate it with a traditional .NET Windows Form in both ways

Comment: my scenario is this, I have a .Windows Universal App and I need to expose some methods to be called from an external .NET Windows Forms App, how can I do that, since WCF doesn't work in Windows Universal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a .Windows Universal App and I need to expose some methods to be called from an external .NET Windows Forms App, how can I do that

You can use [App Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/communicate-with-a-remote-app-service) to call some methods from an external .Net App. As the document says:

> you can run and communicate with app services on remote devices as well. Any Windows-based device can be used as either the home or target device, or both. This gives you an almost limitless number of ways to interact with connected devices without needing to bring an app to the foreground.

Alternatively, you can use [WebSockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/networking/websockets) to achieve that too.

WebSockets creates a two-way communication between client and server using HTTP(S). By triggering the [MessageWebSocket.MessageReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241358) event, you can implement a callback for your methods in UWP side.

Comment: well, I used websocket like Elvis Xia - MSFT said and everything looks good, thanks for the advise.